# {"error":"unsupported_grant_type","error_description":"grant type not supported"} on executing curl command

Tags: apex, rest-api, lightning-experience, curl

I know this must have been posted here and I've tried the solutions I've searched across the web but I am still getting the error

{"error":"unsupported_grant_type","error_description":"grant type not supported"}
when I try to perform a cURL request to my sandbox org.

I've configured the connected app as follows:

Relaxed IP Restrictions
Allowed users to self authorize

Built my cURL request from a Mac terminal: (Tried password with security token also, but same result)

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token' \ --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \ --data-urlencode 'grant_type=password' \ --data-urlencode 'username=xxxxxxx' \ --data-urlencode 'password=xxxxx' \ --data-urlencode 'client_id=xxxxxxxx' \ --data-urlencode 'client_secret=xxxxxxxxx'
    {"error":"unsupported_grant_type","error_description":"grant type not supported"}curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
    curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
    curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
    curl: (6) Could not resolve host: grant_type=password
    curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
    curl: (6) Could not resolve host: xxxx.com.rdc.phase1
    curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
    curl: (6) Could not resolve host: password=xxxxx
    curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
    curl: (6) Could not resolve host: client_id=xxxxxxx
    curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
    curl: (6) Could not resolve host: client_secret=xxxxxx
```

Please advise, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this

```
curl -v https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token 
      -d "grant_type=password" -d "client_id=consumer_key" 
      -d "client_secret=consumer_secret" 
      -d "username=username" -d "password=password"
```

Comment: I tried this and it was success. So is this command similar to Curl POST request ?

Comment: Yes..this command is mentioned in official documents

Comment: Thank you so much.I received the access token from sandbox as response

Comment: Glad it worked. Please mark this as answer so that it could help others.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same situation as OP but the solution isn't working for me. Keep getting 400 requests. Any idea on what could be causing this?

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE). Please see the notes about "me too!" responses & "asking another, different question" in [Why and how are some answers deleted?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers) & be aware that your "answer" will most likely be deleted. Please contribute to SFSE in other ways so that you gain reputation - you only need 15 rep to upvote a question & only 50 to comment under someone else's question. Or you could possibly ask a [new question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/ask), and in it link to this Q or A for reference.